# MySQL connector with Cmake C++

Tags: c++, mysql, cmake

I am trying to build a simple app that inserts data into a database.
I am not sure what the `Cmake` file should look like.
I've downloaded `mysql-connector-c++` zip, unpacked it and placed it inside the project directory.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.22)
project(inserting_database)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 23)
include_directories(mysql-connector-c++)

include_directories(mysql-connector-c++/include/jdbc/cppconn)

link_directories(mysql-connector-c++/lib64/vs14)

add_executable(insert_debug main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(insert_debug curl mysql-connector-c++)
```

in the main I have included

```
#include "include/jdbc/mysql_connection.h"
#include <driver.h>
#include <exception.h>
#include <prepared_statement.h>
```

build fails with error:

```
C:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lcurl

C:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lmysql-connector-c++
```

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a_W4zt5sR1M
I am trying to follow this example, but with `Cmake` in `Clion`.
It is my first project with a database.

Any idea why this is not working?

Comment: I am not sure, what you downloaded with that .zip, but does that contain the prebuilt library files, or does it presume you build and install those at your development system 1st? Look for the corresponding `.a` files.

Comment: I downloaded mysql c++ connector https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/cpp/

Comment: So the MacOS binaries?

Comment: Where is libcurl located? Can you try specifying the directory where libcurl is located in CMakeLists.txt? Also, recommend you to add MinGW tag since it seems you're using it.

Comment: `mysql-connector-c++/lib64/vs14` looks like a build for msvc and not mingw.